# Why doesn't .size() work properly on this ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I've imported a dat file into an ArrayList.  My issue is that, although it prints out all the names in the file, it won't give me the correct size.  Instead, it just prints out 1.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestArray {
    public static void main (String [] args){
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\workspace\\Fund III\\src\\names.dat";

    Scanner sc = null;
    try {

        sc = new Scanner(new File (filePath ));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Makes Array list
    ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Dumps names into array
try{
    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        nameList.add(sc.nextLine());
    }
   }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
    System.out.println(nameList.size());
    System.out.println(nameList);
}
}
```

Comment: Who said that 1 wasn't the correct size?  Perhaps the list only has *one* thing in it.

Comment: How is your file structured? Are all of the names on one line?

Comment: If your loading a Linux file into a Java process running on Windows (or vice-versa), the Scanner may not recognise the "line breaks" correctly and treat the content as a single line.

Comment: Your code works for me.  When pointed at a file with three names on separate lines, it creates an `ArrayList` with size 3, and echoes back the names correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your file has only one line. Here is how to check:

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    nameList.add(line);
    System.out.println("Line: '"+line+"'");
}
```

Run your modified program, and watch for single quotes around your strings. If your output produces multiple lines inside a single pair of quotes, the issue is that your input does not have end-of-line markers expected by the system on which you run your program.

Comment: It's only printing on one line. There's a list of names and they all look like this "JOAN".  Is there any way to separate them so that they're different elements?

Comment: @JonathanOrtiz Use `hasNext()`/`next()` instead of `hasNextLine()`/`nextLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) java doc ...

> The default whitespace delimiter used by a scanner is as recognized by
>   [Character.isWhitespace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-).

Are you sure you understand the content of the file and how it has been created (Linux/Windows).

For example when running a Java process on Linux and reading a file that has been created on Windows, I often have to use the [dos2unix](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) command to correct the file format, otherwise it won't process as expected unless you put extra effort into specifying the correct file encoding in your java code.